# Have I chosen the correct tenses

Tags: tense

Is it correct to say or write that

I tried a new time but it is still not working

past simple because I only did one essay today(however it is true that I made many yesterday.)

Answer (score 1):

You should say:

> I tried **another** time but it is not working.

*new time* does not have a meaning that you intend.

Also I would leave out *still* since this indicates a continuation of some state (success or failure). However you said you were successful before, but not this time.

Comment: What if he tried a *different duration* as input to some apparatus?  That might be "a new time" he was talking of...

Comment: No  I used "still "because the other essays(those I made yesterday) were also a failure.